# Why is my JS Shmup shifting my shots to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

I am trying to modify an existing JS/HTML5 shmup by Jared Mills to go vertical and change the sprites. Changing sprites is easy. Logic mstly works. However, I am having a lot of problems in rendering the shots and collision detection. The code "seems" to work... but the shots are not coming out the right way.

Here is my relevant code (the rest are not active. All I did was spam the space bar to "fire a shot" (call fireLaser()) Please watch the attached animated GIF. Assume canvas of 400x400 pixels

```
 fireLaser() {
  let laser = createLaserElement()
  mainPlayArea.appendChild(laser)
  moveLaser(laser)
}


function createLaserElement() {
  let xPosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(shooter).getPropertyValue('left')) // assume 180px
  let yPosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(shooter).getPropertyValue('top')) // assume 350px
  let newLaser = document.createElement('img')
  newLaser.src = 'images/bullet.png' // green paw
  newLaser.classList.add('laser')
  newLaser.style.left = `${xPosition-40}px` // should be +10, but... 
  newLaser.style.top = `${yPosition-20}px`
  return newLaser
}


function moveLaser(laser) {
  let laserInterval = setInterval(() => {
    let yPosition = parseInt(laser.style.top)
    let monsters = document.querySelectorAll(".monster")
    monsters.forEach(monster => {
      if (checkLaserCollision(laser, monster)) {
        monster.src = "images/explosion.png"   // dead skull
        monster.classList.remove("monster")
        monster.classList.add("dead-monster")
        scoreCounter.innerText = parseInt(scoreCounter.innerText) + 100
      }
    })
    if (yPosition <= 40) {  // shot didn't hit anything and reached the tp
      laser.remove()  // erase it
    } else {
      laser.style.top = `${yPosition - 4}px`  // move 4 pixels up
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

[Recording of my "cat" shooting, but there was no movement...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfYT.gif)

It is as if the "laser" was displaced sideways by the "cat" and other renderings of the "laser". As each are erased, the next somehow was "displaced" back. I checked the .left in the Chrome Inspector... They are all the same. So it's ONLY in the rendering. I suspect the -40 x-offset in createLaserElement is not necessary. But if I don't have it, the shot comes out of that cat's rear end. Which seems to make no sense.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The moment I posted the question I realized the problem was NOT in the code, but the in attached stylesheet, sorry. The stylesheet referred to the object as position:relative, which screwed up the coordinates. After changing it to absolute the problem resolved itself.